# How to call back the object i'm currently creating?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I was doing a little programming about a board game. I can't figure how to use 'this' to let the method know that I am calling back the object i'm using.

```
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *) name
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        name = _name;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) move:(Dice *) die
{
    [die rollDice];
    [_isOn leave:&Player];
    [_isOn move:&Player using:die remainingSteps:die.totalValue];

}
```

as you guys can see, I was asking the _isOn to carry out the function "leave:(Player *)p" where p is the player object created. however, the program kept prompt error saying 'expected expression'

Comment: You need to explain more about what you want and provide more code.  `leave:&Player` is suspicious, assuming `Player` is an objective-c object (which cannot exist outside pointer form).  Also instances *should* start with lowercase and classes with uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

I assume what you are looking for is:

```
[_isOn leave:self];
```

`Player` represents the class itself, while the `leave` method expects a pointer to an *instance* of the class. In Objective-C, the `self` keyword (rather than 'this') refers to the current object instance.